# Why does my users table have a no column error?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, yaml

I am getting the following error after running my tests in the console:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: table users has no column named password: INSERT INTO "users"
```

user_test.rb:

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "a user should enter a first name" do
    user = User.new
    assert !user.save
    assert !user.errors[:first_name].empty?
  end

  test "a user should enter a last name" do
    user = User.new
    assert !user.save
    assert !user.errors[:last_name].empty?
  end

  test "a user should enter a profile name" do
    user = User.new
    assert !user.save
    assert !user.errors[:profile_name].empty?
  end

  test "a user should have a unique profile name" do
    user = User.new
    user.profile_name = users(:adam).profile_name

    assert !user.save
    assert !user.errors[:profile_name].empty?
  end
end
```

users.rb:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
 # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
        :first_name, :last_name, :profile_name

validates :first_name, presence: true

validates :last_name, presence: true

validates :profile_name, presence: true,
        uniqueness: true

has_many :statuses

def full_name
first_name + " " + last_name
end
end
```

users.yml:

```
dan:
  first_name: "Dan"
  last_name: "Can"
  email: "dan@email.com"
  profile_name: "dan"
  password: "123456"
  password_confirmation: "123456"
```

database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
 adapter: sqlite3
 database: db/development.sqlite3
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

What I believe to be my user migrate file:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  create_table(:users) do |t|
  t.string :first_name
  t.string :last_name
  t.string :profile_name

  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Confirmable
  # t.string   :confirmation_token
  # t.datetime :confirmed_at
  # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is     :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at

  ## Token authenticatable
  # t.string :authentication_token


  t.timestamps
end

 add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
 add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
end
end
```

I would like to know what is causing the error, but more importantly why.

Comment: I tried that earlier and got a "command not found"

Comment: What about `rake db:migrate` then `rake db:test:prepare`?

Comment: still a "command not found"

Comment: Are you within your directory where you call `rails console`? Could you also post your `database.yml` for kicks?

Comment: @jason328 a pwd check shows that I am.

Comment: I did not see any .yml files in my db directory

Comment: Look in your `config` folder.

Comment: @amb110395 is that the right file?

Comment: Yes, it is the right file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I removed the `password` and `password_confirmation` columns from the users fixture it passed the test with no errors. I'm told by a friend that is was likely due to an upgrade in devise.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of possibilities here but I will focus on the immediate problem. If your Rake tasks are returning `No command found`, then it may be because Rake isn't installed on your computer. I would start there.

To install Rake, type in your terminal:

```
gem install rake
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is because your users table doesn't have a column named `password`. With `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:test:prepare` you are ensuring that any migrations you created are applied to your database.

Let me know the results.

Comment: That seems odd, because I have done rake db:migrate a bunch of times before with no issue. Is there a command I can punch into the console to see if it is installed? I tried to do the instal and got the following error: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/Jadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rake-10.0.4/.gemtest

Comment: Try `bundle show` and see if rake is on the list that will be displayed. But if you ran it before you must have it installed already. The reason you got the error is because you didn't put `sudo` before `gem install rake`. `Sudo` allows you run commands when you aren't the root user.

Comment: Shows * rake (10.0.4). I'm quite certain I'm the root user, as I am the only one on this laptop.

Comment: Try `bundle update` then run the rake tasks. I'm running out of solutions. Hopefully someone else can enlighten us.

Comment: Shows     Using rake (10.0.4)    my guess is that means it is the current one? After that did the    rake db:migrate    and the    rake db:test:prepare    but still gave the same error on the    ruby -Itest test/unit/user_test.rb

Comment: This is my last suggestion. Delete any files that are located inside the `test/fixtures` folder.

Comment: While that cleared my 4 errors, it still did produce a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'users' for #<UserTest:0x007fe3b9ebbbb8>' error from taking out that user.yml file.  Appreciate you giving it a shot for me though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem you have is, just as the error says, there is no password column in your User table. You have to add it to your migration:

```
t.string   :password
```

Note, however, that I have never used Devise so I may be wrong about this.

Comment: Devise will set up the password for you. Hence why you see `encrypted_password` in the migrations. Devise is also nice enough for you to still use `password` and `password_confirmation` as attributes to the User model.